# HOW TO ADD membershipCreateStatus

Tags: asp.net

This is the code behind of button named "Create". How can i add automatically "membershipCreateStatus" through the condition if. I try to add it manualy and i get an erroe message: "The name 'membershipCreateStatus' does not exist in the current context"

```
    protected void btnAddUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
          membershipCreateStatus            
        }         
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you need to add

using System.Web.Security;

```
protected void btnAddUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
          MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
            MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(Username.Text, Password.Text, Email.Text, passwordQuestion, SecurityAnswer.Text, true, out createStatus);

        }         
    }
```

Comment: Thanks u for your helping, im a begginer developer, im writing my first website. Another problems:when i'm trying to insert a valid value into "Email" textbox. I get that this value that was inserted, is invalid. This is how i wrote part of the code i the aspx file: ValidationExpersion="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\ w +([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" 
this is the message that refer to above code:  Attribute 'ValidationExpersion' is not a valid attribute of element 'RegularExpressionValidator'.

Comment: Ok, please add another question for the issue you are facing now. Also include your code.